# How can i read all files in directory in c++?

Tags: c++, file

I want to read all files in specific directory.
for example
In directory a there are file1.text file2.txt a.txt c.txt

I want to know how many words are included in each file.
I made a code for a file.
But I don't know how to automatically move on next file at same directory.

int EBook::get_total_words()
{

```
ifstream ifs("inputs//a.txt");
int words = 0;
string word;

if (!ifs)
{
    std::cout << "Unable to open file " << '\n';
    exit(1);
}

while (ifs >> word) {
    ++words;
}


return words;
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `std::filesystem` you can do this:

```
std::string path_to_dir = '/some/path/';
for( const auto & entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator( path_to_dir ) ){
    std::cout << entry.path( ) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I also searched this code but I can't understand how to operate this code. Is there any websites that i can search to understand?

Comment: @SWDEVELOPERFROMKR - The code snippet will list all the file names in the directory. Surely you can figure out how to *open* the file instead of displaying the name.

Comment: @SWDEVELOPERFROMKR please explain how can you not operate the code so we can help. This is a minimal example to show you how to obtain path of each file in a directory. As BoP said, you are going to need to do what you actually want inside that for loop. With each iteration, you will get a different file's path from `entry.path()` so you can do whatever you want with it. I just gave a basic example of printing their names. Don't forget adding `#include <filesystem>` and compiling with `-std=c++17` .

Comment: @SWDEVELOPERFROMKR you will need to `#include <filesystem>` and use a C++17 or later compiler

Comment: @nomoresegmentationfaults Thanks and sorry for late replying for example if i have a.txt, b.txt c.txt d.txt file in a same directory then how can i adjust above code to count words?